# unable to save data, parse cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have just started using Parse.com. Trying to save three simple variables.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("WorkTable");
      testObject.put("foo", "bar");
      testObject.put("foo1", "bar");
      testObject.put("fo", "bar");
      testObject.saveInBackground();
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
  }
```

Class used for initialize Parse and auth. ### are real App ID and client Key.

```
  public class ParseApplication extends Application {
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
            Parse.initialize(this, "###", "###");
        }
    }
```

In manifest:

```
<application
        android:name="com.parse.starter.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="###" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="###" />
```

I found this in logs:

```
09-11 11:30:32.540  23532-24173/com.parse.starter D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12 (ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-24): calling run()
09-11 11:30:32.543  23532-24173/com.parse.starter D/libc-netbsd﹕ getaddrinfo: api.parse.com NO result from proxy
09-11 11:30:32.543  23532-24173/com.parse.starter I/System.out﹕ [CDS][DNS]Unable to resolve host "api.parse.com": No address associated with hostname
```

May be it means something?

Credentials are right, checked billion times.
Table "WorkTable" is created, but it's always empty.
What am i doing wrong, please help.

Comment: i still say cross verify application id and client key. everything seems ok if you have configuration mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
            Parse.initialize(this,"key", "key");
            ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
            ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
            defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
            ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
            ParseObject a = new ParseObject("a");
            a.put("shoe");
            a.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

see if this data saves, let me know what happens and give logs

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in your app you will need to remember to set your application id and key as supplied to you by Parse. I did it in an Application object in the onCreate method;

Application.java :

```
public void onCreate() {
    Parse.initialize(this, "Your Application Id", "Your Client Key");
}
```

Then just create new parseobject wherever you required.

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.pinInBackground();
```

Note : Don't forget to specify your application name to manifest' application tag like below :

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: I've did it all. I can see this empty table in Data browser at Parse, but it is empty.

Comment: just try to remove meta tag from your manifest and define your required  columns in parse database.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. Clearly he has already initialized his keys. Also, using pinInBackground is for local datastore. saveInBackground is correct.

Comment: He has edited his answer after my answer before that he did not mentioned above details.